# Using width with hideable menu

Tags: css

I have a problem with setting the size on two DIVs.

I have it like this

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="menubar">
  Menu
  </div>
  <div id="pagecontent">
  Content, other divs
  </div>
</div>
```

Because sometimes I want to use the full width of the screen for showing content, I make it possible to hide/toggle (jquery) the menubar DIV.

CSS:

```
#parent{
    position:           relative;
    width:              100%;
    height:             100%;
}
#menubar{
    height:             100%;
    width:              170px;
    background-color:   #404040;
    color:              white;
    float:              left;
}
#pagecontent{
    width:              100%;
    position:           absolute;
}
```

The problem is now that pagecontent is the full width of it's parent, which it only should be when the menu bar is hidden. When the menubar is not hidden, the width of content should be 100%-170px.

How to solve this in CSS?

Edit: Fixed using jquery:

```
$( "#topbarmenutoggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#menubar" ).toggle()
      if ($( "#menubar" ).is(':visible')){
            $("#pageinnercontent").width('calc(100% - 170px)');
            $("#pageinnercontent").css('left', '170px');
      }else{
            $("#pageinnercontent").width('100%');
            $("#pageinnercontent").css('left', '0px');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Aviod removing the second div element from normal flow by absolute positioning. Instead, give an `overflow` of `hidden` (whatever other than `visible`) to that element.

Comment: I don't believe you will find a CSS only solution to this.  I recommend using javascript to derive the viewport width and set that value-170px into the content.  I can write you a jQuery solution if you so require, but default CSS will not work in this scenario.

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne I do believe that there *is* a CSS solution to achieve this (at least).

Comment: @HashemQolami good idea, I am concerned for the poster though as width:100% will act unpredictably when 'pushed'.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for this -
http://jsfiddle.net/9jyrxxjf/

note I added position: relative on the menu for now, and z-indexes.  Not sure how you are opening and closing the menu.

Additionally you can put overflow: hidden on the parent.

Comment: This was what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9jyrxxjf/1/